# Empty qgz when I open it

Tags: qgis-3, qgz

With QGIS 3.x when I save any project in a qgz format and I try to open it after, they are always with no one layers in the TOC (and canvas...). Every layer is in the same location in the computer...

Anyone has any tip about what could be happening?

Sorry, I wrote the post too quickly...

- I am not getting any warning or error at any time
- The data is stored locally in the computer hard disk.
- The work flow is just:

  - Add some layer (shp / geopackage / raster)
  - Save the project
  - Close QGIS
  - Open QGIS
  - Select the project
- The OS is Windows 10 (I have tried the same flow in a computer with linux and everything is ok).

Comment: We will need more information before any suggestions can be made.  Are you getting any warnings or errors when you open the project after saving?  What is you work flow up to the point of saving?  Are the data stored on removable media?  What operating system are you using? etc...